# Can’t post photos in FB iOS. No setting for it

Tags: ios, photos, facebook

My wife’s iPhone XR has the FB app on it. It will not allow photos to be posted. When you try it says it needs to have access, and takes you to the Facebook settings panel. There is no setting there for photos. There is Siri, notifications, background app refresh and cellular data. Nothing else. On my iPhone there is a page of settings, including photos. I have force quit the app, updated the app, no luck. Suggestions?

Comment: Please add the iOS versions of both iPhones to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you often post photos to Facebook and are OK with letting Facebook access all your photos? If yes, open the Settings app on the iPhone > tap Privacy > Photos > Facebook > All Photos. After this, you'll be able to post photos when using the Facebook app.

If you only want to allow Facebook limited access, follow the above steps but tap Selected Photos. Now tap 'Edit selected photos' and check mark the photos you might want to share on Facebook. After this, you'll be able to post these selected photos when using the Facebook app. To add more photos to the selection, go to Facebook app > tap the 'add photo' button > Manage > Select More Photos > choose the photos > Done. After this, the newly added photos will also become available for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when there's an issue with not being able to access Photos within another app, it's due to lack of permissions. When you attempt to post a photo for the first time, you should get the following prompt within the Facebook app:

[image: Facebook prompt to allow access to Photos on iOS]

If you're not getting that, it's likely that the dialog was dismissed by clicking "Don't Allow" on the following modal:

[image: iOS Photos access modal]

If you don't see that modal when choosing "Continue" in the Facebook app, try removing the app completely, including all local data, and then reinstalling the app from the App Store. That should reset all local permissions for the app and allow you to select "Select Photos..." or "Allow Access to All Photos". The option for "Don't Allow" is not a cancel button and will restrict access to the photo album for as long as the app is installed or you change in system settings.